# How does istream::clear() behave if the stream is actually an ifstream?

Tags: c++, file

I was wondering if calling `clear()` on an `istream` is the same / similar to calling `close()` on an `ifstream`.

My code looks like this:

```
void load_content(std::istream &ifs) {
    std::string line;
    getline(ifs, line);
    ...
    ifs.clear();
}
```

Before, the argument was a `std::ifstream` and `ifs.close()` was called.

But to make it more testable, I changed it do istream such that I can pass filecontents as a stringstream.

Is this safe? In the normal usage of the program, there will always be an `iftream` passed to the function, only in tests it will be a stringstream.

Do I need to do more than this or is this fine?

Comment: You normally don't call `close` explicitly but leave that to the object's destruction to take care of. But no, they are nothing like each other; [`close`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) closes a file, [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) manipulates a stream's error state.

Comment: @molbdnilo calling explicitly helps to check errors that might occur. Anyhow, imho `load_content` is the wrong place to close the file